# Swift: CoreMotion and G-Forces?

Tags: swift, sensors, core-motion, acceleration

I know how to get the gravity data with CoreMotion, but I am not sure what the data actually says.

I would like to show the current G-Forces to the User, but is the sensor data already the G-Force or how can this be converted to G's?

Right now I just read the sensor data for the acceleration for the 3-axis, but I do not understand the output-data:

```
//MARK: Properties
var manager = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.5
    manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
        if let acData = data {
            let gravityX = acData.gravity.x
            let gravityY = acData.gravity.y
            let gravityZ = acData.gravity.z
            print(gravityY, gravityY, gravityZ)
        }
    }        
}
```

The values (for x, y, z) I get are:

-0.0363383330404758 -0.0363383330404758 -0.999310553073883

I know that the g-force on the z axis is about 1 when resting (eg. the phone is lying flat on the table), but Xcode gives me a value of -0.999310553073883. Is this already the g-force for the z axis? But why is it negative?

The idea is that like on a roller coaster, where it says it has 4G I would like to display the current G's to the user and -0,998638593... is not very helpful here.

The interesting thing here is that when I shake the phone those values do not change a lot, but when I print instead of gravity the acceleration they get pretty I when I apply a hard shake to the phone:

```
print(data.userAcceleration.z)
```

Would this be the right g-force?

Comment: you just need to summarise the three vectors to get the actual vector (=direction and strength) of the G-force what pressures the phone at the current moment; you can find elementary operations with vectors on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector), if you need more precision, you may need to think about finding a balanced position and use that as a relative zero point.

Comment: But would that give me somehow the actually g-force? Again the roller coaster example: It's says for example that on coaster the max positive g-force is 4 and the max negative g-firce -1.2 - how can this vector be used to calculate that? I mean it cannot be so difficult because there are dozens of apps out there showcasing g-forces (usually apps for racing and cars).

Comment: summarising the 3 vectors gives you the vector of G-Force.